# camel route to dowload file from ftp. Can we introduce a pre processor before the route gets invoked?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, sftp

Hi have the below route.

Now i want to interject or have a preproccsor bean being invoked before the route starts downloading file from ftp. I want to do this to serialize as I have a distributed node setup and want to use Zookeeper to serialize downloads one at a time. All nodes running this route is causing a problem. Is there any preprocessor hook or bean that i can use to do this.

```
 <route id="download-from-ftp" autoStartup="{{cnpp.route.startup}}" 
     startupOrder="1">
        <from
                 uri="uri"/>

        <to uri="{{download.filelocation}}"/>
        <to uri="{{backup.filelocation}}"/>
        <process ref="updateDownloadedProcessor"/>
    </route>
```

Comment: No you cannot, but you can use a route policy, or event notifier to get callbacks before route is started/stopped etc or an exchange is created / done etc.

Answer (score 0):

did you get a chance to see Camel Interceptors, specially 'interceptFrom '.
http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html

> **InterceptFrom**
>
> InterceptFrom is for intercepting any incoming Exchange, in any route (it intercepts all the from DSLs). This allows you to do some custom behavior for received Exchanges. You can provide a specific uri for a given Endpoint then it only applies for that particular route.

also have a look on AdviceWith.
http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

May be you can advice an existing route by adding InterceptFrom.